# Android: org.apache.http async task Failed to work

Tags: android, apache, build, sdk

Am trying to using **org.apache.http.legacy** library for asynctask

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

I heard that in API 23 **"org.apache.http"** is not working
so i tried this

```
android {

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

After that I sync the project , but no result

Still this much of library is not importing properly

```
import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
```

This problem arise when I change to API Level 21 to API Level 23. Because i want to work with API level 23

This is the method that am using for parsing

```
    new AsyncHttpClient().get("url",
                      new TextHttpResponseHandler() {

                          @Override
                          public void onStart() {

                          }

                          @Override
                          public void onRetry(int retryNo) {

                          }

                          @Override
                          public void onFailure(int arg0, Header[] arg1,
                                                String response, Throwable arg3) {

                          }

                          @Override
                          public void onSuccess(int arg0, Header[] arg1,
                                                String response) {

                                                }
```

Comment: Make sure that you are on version 1.3.0 of the Gradle for Android plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was said that a org.apache.http.legacy.jar in Android/sdk/platforms/android-23/optional,

So we can add that library in out application lib folder
after that use  
`useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'`

and then sync it

Answer (score 1):

As `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` was deprecated in API level 22 and is no longer supported in API level 23, Please use `openConnection()`. Please see the code below.

```
URL url = new URL("urlString");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");   
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
String response = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(is, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(response);
```

Comment: openConnection() means , how to use that @Chintan Bawa

Comment: Please check my answer @BinilS

Comment: please check my updated questions, i mention how am trying to parse the url @ Chintan Bawa

Comment: Please use AsyncTask instead of AsyncHttpClient() and paste above code in doInBackground. @BinilS

Comment: I found a solution we can add http.leagcy library , then it will solve the issue , I post my answer . Any way thaks for your timely help @Chintan Bawa